# How do you count words in a df column and save it so that it matches the word count with ID?

Tags: r, merge, word-count

This is probably a really simple issue but I haven't been able to figure it out after looking at previous threads.

I have a df with two columns: ID and Response, the Response variable is a string with multiple words entered separated by a space.

I first split the words by a space:

```
words <- str_split(d_words$Response, " ")

#Make sure everything is split properly:

words2 <- gsub("\n", " ", words)

#Split again:

words3 <- str_split(words2, " ")

#And then count:

wordcount <-lapply(words3, length)
```

This gives me the correct word count for each row, but I can't seem to merge the original d_words df with the wordcount. How do I retrieve or maintain the ID variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply `cbind(d_words, wordcount)`, since you did not change the ordering?